# how to redirect a page in angular and using node js

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am checking a login and after that sending a status to angular controller, from controller I am redirecting to other pages and again checking route with angular route, everything working but content got inserted layout inside layout

i am using angular with node js
engine is jade and have a layout(master page)

Comment: what you are trying to acheive

Comment: redirect a page to other page using angular but in angular page is not refreshed and just add a # symbol, http://xy.com/login/#contact

contact is node js page and i am using layout


i want when the page call from angular and after checking angular route then is should display as calling from node js